conversion of  vectors of regular icosahedron to unit vectors appear to be wrong.
I understand that  common way of identifying the cartesian coordinates of an icosahedron is by using the coordinates, where  is the golden ratio: (1+√5)/2) or cos(π/5.0)
(0,±1,±1),(±1,±1,0),(±1,0,±1)
I believe that expanding this out gives me the location of the 12 vertices of a regular icosahedron with side length 2:
    π = math.pi
     = math.cos(π / 5.0)
    ico_vertices = [
        (0, -1, -), (0, -1, +), (0, +1, -), (0, +1, +),
        (-1, -, 0), (-1, +, 0), (+1, -, 0), (+1, +, 0),
        (-, 0, -1), (-, 0, +1), (+, 0, -1), (+, 0, +1)
    ]

In order to get those points onto a unit sphere, I think I am right to normalise them.
    iv = np.array(ico_vertices)
    iv_n = ((iv[:, None] ** 2).sum(2) ** 0.5).reshape(-1, 1)
    ico = iv / iv_n  # normalised  vertices. 

Converting them to GoogleMaps friendly latitude/longitudes (bearing in mind that google may not be a spherical projection) as follows:
    google_ll = [tuple([
        math.degrees(math.atan2(z, math.sqrt(x * x + y * y))),
        math.degrees(math.atan2(y, x))])
        for x, y, z in ivu]

Here is the result projected onto google maps.


Using another set of coordinates I get the following - which looks much, much better:

There is something wrong with the way in which I am deriving latitude and longitude from the golden ratio coordinates.  At first I thought I was just dealing with the way Google was projecting the points, but I can see that it is not the case.
Where is my error, and how do I get correct it?

$\cos(\pi/5)$ isn't equal to $\varphi > 1$... but to $\varphi/2$.

omg.. Jean Marie... thank you so much.. So easy to make a tiny mistake, and then hunt everywhere for the wrong result!
